# Wi-Fi automatically gets disconnected

Tags: wireless, drivers, internet, thinkpad, netgear

Laptop : Lenovo ThinkPad x120e
Router : Netgear N-150 wireless router WGR614v10
OS : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 64 bit

Problem is, sometimes my netgear wi-fi connection automatically gets disconnected, more than that Ubuntu doesn't even shows the netgear wi-fi in the list of wi-fi in range. But when I turn off wi-fi and then turn it on again, it automatically connects the netgear. I'd done some research online, but nothing worked. As far as I think, it looks like an driver issue, but I don't know how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance... :-)